# Does the Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter work with 2048x1152 resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, dvi

I'm thinking of buying the new Macbook Air and I was wondering whether the [Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter](http://store.apple.com/my/product/MB570Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ) will work with my 23" Samsung LCD with a 2048 x 1152 resolution.

Comment: BTW I just bought a third-party adapter from Monoprice.com. It works the same as the Apple adapter and is far less expensive at US$6.65 plus shipping.

Comment: Unfortunately I think they don't ship to my country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.apple.com/macbookair/specs.html

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an
>   external display, both at millions of colors

I don't think the adapter has any impact on what resolutions are supported.